# Convert an InputBox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert an InputBox to Int32 but it doesn't work, anyone know how resolve that ?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] tab = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; ++i)
    {
        tab[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox("Value", "Array")); 
       // Error here
    }
    textBox1.Text = "Plus petit: " + Smaller(tab).ToString();         
    //textBox1.Text = "Plus grand: " + result.ToString();
}

private int Smaller(int[] array)
{
    var result = array[0];
    foreach (int tabs in array)
    {
        if (result > tabs)
        {
            result = tabs;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: Does `Interaction.InputBox` return anything?

Comment: What line does your exception occur on?

Comment: You need to be more clear.
The code does not work as well as you wrote. @user3813238

Comment: You told `tab` to be `null`, and it is.

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing your array. Change `int[] tab = null;` to  `int[] tab = new int[numericUpDown1.Value];`

If you not initialize your array, it will stay null and therefore will `tab[i]` always be null. The value in the square brackets will tell the compiler haw large your array will be.

If you do not know how large the array will be, you don't want to know or you just don't care, you might want to use `List<T`>:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    List<int> tab = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; ++i)
    {
        tab.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox("Value", "Array")));
       // Error here
    }
    textBox1.Text = "Plus petit: " + Smaller(tab).ToString();         
    //textBox1.Text = "Plus grand: " + result.ToString();
}

private int Smaller(List<int> list)
{
    var result = list[0];
    foreach (int tabs in list)
    {
        if (result > tabs)
        {
            result = tabs;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

//EDIT:
If you want to save yourself some code and just want the smallest int value out of that list use

```
textBox1.Text = "Plus petit: " + tab.Min().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

In `button1_Click()` `tab` is null so you cannot assign to `tab[i]`.
You should first make `tab = new int[numericUpDown1.Value];`